# read all files in a directory, then add the content of each file into a listbox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to do something that seems simple but since I'm still new to VB.NET, I need some assistance here.

I want to read a directory that has a few hundred txt files in it. Then, add the content of the file into a listbox, but all in 1 line per file. So lets say the program looks through the folder and the first file it comes across is **info.txt**. The content of the file is :

"asdasdasdasdasd2312323" on line 1 then "2321321213123213" on line 2. If I try to add the content of this file into a listbox, it would be 2 lines. I just want only 1 line in the listbox.

I know how to loop through a folder and read all the files in it but I dont know how to put the content of the files into a listbox.

Comment: Look into FileSystem object here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw67h925.aspx .This is a great start for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class it has  Shared Methods called [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will the Lines of the File.  This example will work for both.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp\Data") 'put your directory path here
        Try
            ListBox1.Items.Add(File.ReadAllLines(f)(0)) 'Read the first line of each file
        Catch ex As ArgumentNullException
            ListBox1.Items.Add("[NO DATA]")   'If no Data catch Error 
        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
            ListBox1.Items.Add("[NO DATA]")   'If no Data catch Error
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that bit of code, it helped me a lot. If I wanted to read ALL the content instead of just the first like, I just have to remove the (0) right?

Comment: Yes, then you would need to use the `listbox.AddRange` Method instead of the `Add` Method. All the zero is doing is selecting the first line of the file.

Comment: I'll go ahead and mess around with it a bit and try to understand it some more :) Thank you so much for your help sir